# Which is the right place to call a functions in android when it has several activity class

Tags: android

I have some queries regarding the life cycle activity of an android. I have a function which is used to set reminders in the devices calendar. Now my question is that where should I write this function so that when the user exit or pause from the app it will call this function.

Now, if I have 10 activity class and if I call this function on the `onDestroy` method of first activity then it is called only when I exit from the first activity, means if the user moves to the 5 activity and from there if it click the home button then this function is not called.

So what is the solution for that? Whether I should call this function in each activity `onDestroy` method or there is a way to solve this out?

Comment: You have 10 activities all running on the same time? I think that's a bit unusual... are you sure it's necessary? maybe you should use a Tab activity or something similar to manage all those activities.

Comment: Actually i have three activity that are manage using Tab Activity...but rest of my activity are manage using option menu button and therefore when i went to an activity that are open by option menu and then click home button from that activity then it doesn't call the onpause() or onDestroy() method of activity that are manage by tabActivity..and i call my function onDestroy of tab activity..

Comment: Then in that case you should write it on the onPause method of your main class (probably the TabActivity class). The onPause method for this class will be called in the scenario you have described as the main activity is guaranteed to be on the activities stack.

Comment: I tried it..but suppose i went to the activity that i open using options menu..then in that activity i made some changes that should be saved to the device calendar and then click the home button from that activity..then i doesn't call that function that is written on the tab activity of onPause() method.

Comment: You're probably right as the main activity's onPause was called before when you opened the new options menu activity. Why do you need to do this update to the calender when the user quits the application? Can't you do it whenever something needs to be changed, regardless of what activity is currently running and independent of activity lifecycle?

Comment: yeh you are right..but there are two problems arises in my case. First one is that if i call the onPause() method of the tab Activity then when i try to open the option menu activity it takes time to open..which is bad for user..

Comment: can we continue our discussion on chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6955/discussion-between-anshuman-and-smichak)

Answer (score 0):

**Now my question is that where should i write this function in so that when the user exit or pause from the app it will call this function.**

You need to call your method on `onPause()`.

Comment: suppose i write it onPause() of first activity..then is it work it i clik the home button from 3rd activity...

Comment: Activity life cycle is for only one activity....You will have to implement Activity like something...

Comment: You can read this "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html".

Comment: Sorry, now see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html